# Too many characters in character literal asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am getting a following error "Too many characters in character literal" when I try to run a javascript location.href during the onclick of the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnManageRoles" runat="server" Text="Manage Roles" Width="80%" 
    onclick="location.href='~/Users/CreateUser.aspx'"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnManageRoles" runat="server" Text="Manage Roles" Width="80%" 
    PostBackUrl="~/Users/CreateUser.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Should this use [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) instead?

You may also want to stop the postback, as Jeff suggests.  To handle that, set the `UseSubmitBehavior` attribute to false.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnManageRoles" 
            runat="server" 
            Text="Manage Roles" 
            Width="80%" 
            OnClientClick="location.href='~/Users/CreateUser.aspx'"  
            UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Comment: OnClientClick will still cause a postback that will negate the script.

Comment: Then also use `UseSubmitBehavior="False"`.